# Is there a variable available that will allow me to discover the Capistrano role from within a task?

Tags: capistrano, task, role

I have two tasks for different roles that are virtually identical.  The only difference is that a command they're running has an argument that is equal to the role name.  Is it possible to combine these two tasks to a single task using the role name as a variable?

The pastie below shows before and after examples of what I'm looking for.  I'd prefer not to repeat the code as in the before example, where the only difference is the name of the role.

http://pastie.org/4496316

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the role variable exists but I know that the server variable exists andyou should be able to get the roles of that server from the variable.